# HttpClientErrorException handling with RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate

I have a method to call an API using RestTemplate like this:

```
public void validateOtps (ValidateOtpRequestDto requestDto, String otpId){
        try{
            HttpEntity<ValidateOtpRequestDto> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestDto);
            restTemplate.exchange(authServiceUrl + "/authentication-service/otps/" + otpId, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        }catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
            log.error(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But everytime the program throw an HttpClientErrorException, the message is not like what I expected. The response I get is :

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "400 : [{\"timestamp\":\"2021-11-08T16:40:41.693+00:00\",\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"OTP doesnt match\",\"path\":\"/authentication-service/authentication-service/otps\"}]",
    "error": null
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "OTP doesnt match",
    "error": null
}
```

Is there any way(s) to achieve what I expected?

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
throw new HttpClientErrorException(e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
```

change `e.getMessage()` to `e.getResponseBodyAsString()`